# Minimum value of $b$ in LCM

Tags: number-theory

> Find the minimum positive integer value of $b$ such that $$\text{lcm}(a,b) > \text{lcm}(a,391)$$ for some positive integer $a$.

Note that $391 = 17 \cdot 23$. Let $a = ck$ and $b = dk$ where $k = \gcd(a,b)$. If $a$ is relatively prime to $391$, then we have $\text{lcm}(a,b) = cd k > 391a = 391ck$. Thus $d > 391$. If $b = 392$, then let $a = 391$ to satisfy the conditions.

I didn't see how to do the case where $a$ is not relatively prime to $391$.

Comment: This problem is the same as one that came out in the Central American and Caribbean Mathematical Olympiad: see the original problem: https://www.jovenestalento.edu.sv/omcc/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/dia-1-eng.pdf

Comment: @RicardoLargaespada Note that the OP did *not* include the $a \lt 391$ condition in the posted question (though it *is* present in the .pdf you linked). Until/unless they do, the answer you posted is a good one, but to a different question than literally asked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that: $$lcm(x,y)\cdot MCD(x,y)=xy.$$

Then the inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{ab}{MCD(a,b)}>\frac{391a}{MCD(391,a)} \Rightarrow b>\frac{391\cdot MCD(a,b)}{MCD(a,391)}$$

If $MCD(a,391)\le 23$, then $b>17\cdot MCD(a,b)$. Then it is easy to prove that $a=23$ generate $b=18$ and this is the minimum value in this case.

If $MCD(a,391)=391$, then $b>MCD(397k,b)$. Then it is easy to prove that $b=2$ is the minimum value.

Definitely $b=2$ is the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be $b=1$, but
$$
\mathrm{lcm}(391,2)>\mathrm{lcm}(391,391).
$$